# Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I have this error :

> Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

from the line 7 in `home.html` template :

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

#### From home.html

```
<h1>Welcome to Jeremie's blog</h1>

<h2>Latest Posts</h2>

{% for posts in posts.all %}

<a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
<br />
{{ posts.pub_date_pretty }}
<br />
<img src = "{{ post.image.url }}" />
<br />
{{ posts.summary }}
<br />
<br />

{% endfor %}
```

#### From posts_details.html

```
{{ post.title }}
<br />
{{ posts.pub_date_pretty}}
<br />
<img src = "{{ post.image.url }}" />
<br />
{{posts.summary}}
<br />
<br />
```

#### From urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_details, name="post_detail"),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

#### From views.py

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('pub_date')
    return render(request, 'posts/home.html', {'posts':posts})

def post_details(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'posts/posts_detail.html', {'post':post})
```

#### From models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100]
```

It seems that `post.id` isn't available in the template. However, it is well defined in `views.py`.

Could anyone be able to tell me how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Your error is happening in home.html but you have posted the view that renders post_detail.html. Where is the view that renders home.html? And please show the rest of that template too.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not being consistent in your home.html template on whether the variable is `post` or `posts`. Pick one - `post` makes more sense - and stick to it.

```
{% for post in posts.all %}

<a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{{ post.pub_date_pretty }}
<img src = "{{ post.image.url }}" />
{{ post.summary }}

{% endfor %}
```

(Also, not related but note that it's extremely poor practice to use `br` tags like that. Please use proper semantic markup and use CSS to manage the space between elements.)

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity With the added info this is obviously the right answer, but just to follow up on the `br` issue: one could also give a reason for not using them. :) The best reason I know for not using them is that the size of a `br` element varies from browser to browser and you won't get a consistent break height with `br`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have `post.id` available in the template, probably because the post isn't created yet. If I don't know your logic patterns, I can't tell you exactly why the `post.id` isn't there, but you see that `post.id` is an empty string from the error message: `Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P[0-9]+)/$']` where the arguments is a tuple of one item that is an empty string, namely this: `('', )`. In the quotations there should be the ID, a number.

Comment: Could you suggest anything I could change in my code? Honestly, I can't see what I could change in my code?

Comment: In fact, `post` has been created in `models.py`, but you are right to tell that post.id isn't perceived by the system.... I can't see why, because it's been two weeks I program with django